# Select all rows with WHERE clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have two tables:
The First has these columns:

```
id 
sender 
recipient 
description
date
```

and the second has these columns:

```
id
name
```

and *sender* and *recipient* are foreign key that reference to id of the second table.

I try to select all rows in the first table.

```
SELECT a.id, a.description, b.name as sender, b.name as recipient, a.date FROM table_A a JOIN table_B b WHERE a.sender=b.id AND a.recipient=b.id ORDER BY date DESC
```

But it shows only rows where sender = recipient. How can I show all rows with unique data in each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.description, b.name AS sender, c.name AS recipient, a.date 
FROM table_A a 
LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.sender = b.id 
LEFT JOIN table_B c ON a.recipient = c.id 
ORDER BY a.date DESC;
```